# When using "mv" command for moving and renaming, script sees it as a directory instead of new filename

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have a question regarding the `mv` command.

In order to move and rename the file, I did `mv file someDir/File2` in my terminal and it moved file into `someDir` with new name called `File2`.

However, when I do it with shell script, it sees the `File2` part as a directory, instead of the new name for the file.

So I have two variables, `NEWDir=newDir`, `NEWF=newName`

```
for i in *.txt ; do
  mv $i $NEWDIR/$NEWF
done
```

I  run this script, it says the following:

```
mv: target 'newName' is not a directory.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`mv` requires the destination to be a directory only if more than one source argument is given.

In this case, that can be caused by your variables being split due to lack of quoting. Use double quotes -- as http://shellcheck.net/ directs -- around *all* expansions.

```
for i in *.txt ; do
  mv "$i" "$NEWDIR/$NEWF"
done
```

Note that only the last file iterated over will actually be left behind with the given name -- the rest will be overwritten by their successors.